# How to save an object that contains a list of integers in a postgres database

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

i have an object called `Cart` i want to save it in the database with an array/list of integers that rappresents `Product`'s id.

This is my `Cart` class at the moment:

```
public class Cart {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "customer_fk")
private Integer customerFk;

@Column(name = "product_list")
private List<Integer> productList;

}
```

i saw that postgres has the `integer[]` datatype

I'm using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` to create the database

How do i tell to spring and jpa to save that list as an integer in the DB?
(if i can)
Is this a good solution?

I actually found a solution that works, using Strings, but im too curious to see if find a way to do it with arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical approach here would be to maintain a table of products and then map carts to products in a one to many relationship.  You could try:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cart")
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "customer_fk")
    private Integer customerFk;

    @Column(name = "product_list")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Product> productList;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_Cart")
    private Cart cart;
 
    // more fields, getters and setters
}
```

This is not a complete implementation, but the idea is that each product ID should exist in a dedicated products table, and each cart entity should track its product references via a foreign key relationship.

Comment: Yeah usually the canonical way works for me, but i'm doing this project for myself to experiment new things and see what works and what doesn't. 

For example here i was trying to keep the two entities unrelated and using less rows on the DB ... clearly i got stuck in an unnecessary dilemma

The solution i was trying to find wont even work... if i save a Product id as an integer in a table how can i know if that Product even exists in the Product table....

Im about to do seppuku

Thanks anyway, you helped me debug my brain